# How to get data of any year of month in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table where my data stored like below and I want data between between Sep 1st and Sep 30th of **any year**

**Id     region     date**

1   Green   2002-sep-10  
2   Green   2002-Jan-01 
2   Red 2002-Feb-01  
 
3   Green   2002-Aug-20 
 4  Green   2002-Aug-01 
 4  Green   2002-Sep-01 
 5  Green   2002-Aug-01  
6   Green   2001-Sep-01

i tried with below queries but not getting right result

Select * from record where date (date,”%D-%b”) >= “01-sep” and date (date,”%D-%b”) <= “30-sep” );

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And store dates as dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `month` function to extract the month:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  MONTH(`date`) = 9
```

Comment: Do not forget to convert `date` column from text to date, for example, using [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/es/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. `SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(\`date\`, '%Y-%M-%d')) ...`.